# Convergence rate of the mean and variance of a normal variable - Numerical simulation

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, matlab

I am simulating in Matlab a Normal Random Variable $X$ with mean $E(X)=0$ and variance $\text{var}(X)=1$, using the built-in `randn`function.

However I am noticing that in order for the mean $(\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N X_n)$ and variance $(\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N X_n^2 - (\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N X_n)^2)$ of the set of realizations $(X_n)_{n\in[1..N]}$ of this random variable to reach $0$ and $1$, respectively, with an error lower than $0.01\%$, I need $N$ to be at least higher than $10^4$.

Is there any way to reach a mean and variance of the set of realizations close to the theoretical values with less than $0.01\%$ error but with much less realizations $N$ (on the order of 10 typically). In order words is there any other way to program a probability distribution in Matlab that converges faster than `randn` to a gaussian distribution with given mean and variance?

Comment: Get two random numbers, one in the range $[0.99,1.01]$ to be the desired variance and the other to be in the range $[-0.01,0.01]$ to be the desired mean.  Then take your simulated standard normal $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_{10}$ and rescale and relocated them so the $Y_i=a+bX_i$ have this target mean and target variance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't understand clearly the meaning of *rescale and relocate*. Moreover what are $a$ and $b$. Are they the random numbers in the range $[0.99, 1.01]$ and $[-0.01, 0.01]$ ? Are these random numbers generated by a uniform distribution ?

Comment: It seems to me that writing $Y = a + bX$ with $a \neq 0$ and $b \neq 1$ leads to $E(Y) = a+bE(X)$ and $\text{var}(Y) = b^2 \text{var}(X)$. Hence it is problematic since I want $Y$ to have the same mean and variance than $X$ but converge faster in terms of statistics...

Comment: So you want $Y$ to be the same as $X$ but different?

Comment: In fact yes. $Y$ should have the same statistics for an infinite number of realizations, but converge faster than X. What I am looking for is a numerical way of simulating the gaussian variable that converges faster than `randn` as a function of the number of realizations.

Answer (score 2):

Your observation is very correct: sample mean converges to a limiting Normal with $O(1/\sqrt{n})$ rate, thanks to the **central limit theorem**. So you used $n=10^4$ points to get an error of $\varepsilon=10^{-2}$.

Unfortunately, also by the CLT no distirbution can have a sample mean that converge faster than $O(1/\sqrt{n})$, provided that its variance is finite.
So if you are using sample mean of $n$ independent random variables, nothing can beat what you currently have.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to produce a small random sample from a Normal distribution that is guaranteed to have a sample mean and sample variance within $0.01\%$ of the population mean and population variance.

---

The key insight here is that even if you have a method of producing *perfect* random samples from a standard Normal distribution, the samples will not have the same mean and variance as the underlying distribution of the population. In other words, if you are really sampling from a Normal distribution you expect variability in your sample mean and sample variance, for a given sample size. Finding a way to get rid of that variability would force you to either produce something that is not a random sample or did not come from a Normal distribution.

The error in Matlab's `randn` comes from (1) machine precision limitations inherent to any finite computation and (2) the fact that it uses a pseudo random number generator. Both of these limitations are inherent to any computational implementation that produces samples from a probability distribution in a repeatable way. Matlab `R2016A` and other modern versions default to the Mersenne Twister method, which produces high quality pseudo random numbers. The error from the generator and the machine precision is much less than $0.01\%$.

Almost all of the difference between your sample mean and the population mean comes from the randomness in the Normal distribution itself, so **it's best to think of that difference as variability rather than error**.

If you need a small set of numbers that has sample mean and sample variance close to the population values, you could for example take $\{-1.32,-0.54,0.56,1.3\}$. This set of numbers has $(\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N X_n) = 0$ and $(\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N X_n^2 - (\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N X_n)^2) = 1.0094$ $^*$. However, I explicitly chose these numbers - they were *not* randomly sampled from a Normal distribution.

The main conclusion is that the variability in the sample is a good thing because it represents the true variability in samples from a Normal distribution. If you're using the normal random numbers as an input to further simulation, consider [variance reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_reduction) techniques to address this problem while maintaining rigor in your random sampling.

---

$^*$ I'm using your formula for variance but you should carefully consider which [sample variance](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SampleVariance.html) you want to use.